# Image navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a side navigating menu bar with the help of html css. The problem is that I want the menu items to open after I click a small image which is located on the top left side of the page. (The image is my webpage logo.)

Can anyone tell me how to make it so that when the top left small logo is clicked the menu bar slides below it and have menu items in it?

Comment: This question belongs in normal http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr"><img src="image.gif" alt="image"
 style="border:none;" /></a>

 <div id="sidr">
 <div class="logo">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/300x100" alt="">

</div>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
```

and the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#simple-menu').sidr();
});
```

Comment: Put <image> tag under the <a> tag. now you can click the image to display the menu.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind using a jQuery plugin have a look at [sidr](https://github.com/artberri/sidr) it is very simple to use.

```
<a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr">Toggle menu</a>
<div id="sidr">
  <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x100" alt="">          
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#simple-menu').sidr();
});
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2ubqfve9/)

Comment: Thank Sir. That is what i wanted. Just a simple question , can the toggle menu be a logo?

Comment: Yes, it can be anything. here the anchor #simple-menu toggles the main menu, you can place an image instead or any other HTML element. Have a look at the documentation and demos. Let us know if you have any problem